# Gets an error error in Kafka producer when creating topic but the topic is created on the Kafka server

Tags: java, timeout, apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka producer 10.2.1 to create a topic and to write to topic, when I create the topic I get the following error, but the topic is created:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:774)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:494)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:440)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:360)
    at kafka.AvroProducer.produce(AvroProducer.java:47)
    at samples.TestMqttSource.messageReceived(TestMqttSource.java:89)
    at mqtt.JsonConsumer.messageArrived(JsonConsumer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:184)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
msg org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
loc org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
cause org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
excep java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

All suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: A producer can't create a topic. The Admin Client API can do that. The topic is created because there is the topic auto creation (auto.create.topics.enable property) enabled on the broker (by default). Can you show the code ?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I  found a solution, and I have tried to explain the "issue" in a comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use KafkaProducer to create a topic *(So I'm not quite sure how you managed to create the topic, unless you did it previously via a different method such as the kafka admin shell scripts)*. Instead you use the AdminUtils supplied by Kafka library.

I recently achieved both of the requirements you are after, and you'd be surprised how easy it is to achieve. Below is a simple code example showing you how to create a topic via AdminUtils, and how to then write to it.

```
class Foo {

    private String TOPIC = "testingTopic";
    private int NUM_OF_PARTITIONS = 10;
    private int REPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;

    public Foo() {


        ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient( "localhost:2181", 15000, 10000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$ );
        ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils( zkClient, new ZkConnection( "localhost:2181" ), false);

        if ( !AdminUtils.topicExists(zkUtils, TOPIC) ) {
            try {
                AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, TOPIC, NUM_OF_PARTITIONS, REPLICATION_FACTOR, new Properties(), Enforced$.MODULE$);

                Properties producerConfig = new Properties();

                producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
                producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
                producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

                KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfig);

                // This is just to show you how to write but you could be more elaborate
                int i = 0;

                while ( i < 11 ) {
                    ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, ("This is line number " + i));
                    producer.send(rec);
                    i++;
                }

                producer.closer();
            } catch ( AdminOperationException aoe ) {
                aoe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Remember that if you want to delete topics, by default in the settings this is disabled. The config file you use when starting Kafka *(by default it is ${kafka_home}/config/server.properties)*, add the following line if it doesn't already exist and is set to false or commented out:

```
delete.topic.enabled=true
```

You'll then have to restart the server and can delete topics either via Java or the command line tools supplied.

**NB**

It's always a good idea to close producers / consumers when you are finished with them, as shown in the code example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and coments. Our Kafka is set to auto generate topics, from the messages. I found out what was the issue, I'm running the Client on my windows PC and I was using the IP address of the Kafka server when connecting to the Kafka, but I think that somehow in the meta data from the topic creation, the kafkaserver name is returned, so I added the IP address and hostname of the Kafka server to my host file, and it works.

Comment: Ahh okay, that's a bit unusual that that happened! But glad it all works